# Is the Shehechiyanu bracha recited when eating an esrog fruit?

Tags: blessing, eating, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shehecheyanu

Is the Shehechiyanu bracha recited when eating an esrog fruit?
Is seasonal needed?

Comment: Could you [clarify](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/34724/edit) what you mean by "Is seasonal needed?"? Do you mean to ask whether the _esrog_ being eaten must be from the current season? or whether seasonality of a species is necessary, as a rule, for saying _shehechiyanu_? or what?

Answer (score 2):

[Kovaitz Bais Aharon V'Yisroel 103](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13063&st=&pgnum=149&hilite=) has the following roundup.

Orach Chaim 225:6 a fruit that does not regenerate yearly, you do not make a Shehechiyanu on it. Mishna Berura 225:6:16 says this is for example a Esrog. Mishna Berura 225:6:16:19 refers to the Shaarei Efraim and Mor Uketziya.

However Kaf Efraim 225:43 in the name of the Shaar Efraim says one would make a Shehechiyanu upon eating from an Esrog.

The Sefer Pri HaAdama 1:26 questions the Be'er Hataiv for mentioning in the name of the Shaar Efraim that would not make a Shehechiyanu upon eating a Esrog.

Ben Ish Chai Parshas Re'eh 11 says one should not say Shehechiyanu when eating Esrog since  the Shehechiyanu we make on it when we shake it on Succos includes eating it during the year.

Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky used to make a Shehechiyanu when he ate it, however in the more recent years he stopped.

Comment: but what about nishtaneh hateva? Does any of this apply if the esrog is not truly fit for human consumption? I ask this as a halachic point.

Comment: @Josh Waxman: I eat Esrog every year, and I am alive and well Boruch Hashem. I do not eat the peel, only the inside, and as you know an Esrog has a thick peel. I do not think there is any danger in eating it.

Comment: Baruch Hashem. I would not advise this, before doing research on it. I read about this in (iirc) Mishpacha magazine, how they dip it in heavy chemicals. One never knows the long term effects, and how it might effect people with weaker constitutions, etcetera. Also, there are recipes for using the peel: http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/112933/dont-discard-that-etrog

Answer (score 2):

The Piskei Tshuvos 225:17:footnote 124 brings many shittos who say not to make a shecheyanu.A few: Sidur Yaavetz ,Eishal Avraham,Leket Yosher and more.

Some reasons brought are ,its not fit to eat unless its fried and one can't tell between old and new.One already made a brachah on it during the time of its mitzvah and got pleasure from its sight.Another reason is it is not a fruit from year to year because it can last longer than a year on a tree. See it inside if available to you.

Answer (score 1):

The sefer תהלה לדוד discusses at length the various opinions about reciting שהחיינו when eating an esrog, and [at the end](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20613&st=&pgnum=70&hilite=), he concludes:

> 1) If one eats an esrog before Succos one may bless on it שהחיינו. And such was the custom of the Sages of Yerushalayim, to bless the brachah of שהחיינו on the second night of Rosh Hashanah.
>
> 2) If one eats an esrog after Succos, since he has already fulfilled his obligation of שהחיינו when he sees the esrog when he took the Arba Minin, he should not say שהחיינו.
>
> 3) On the confection which is made from an esrog in all situations one should not say שהחינו.

Answer (score -2):

### **No**

Nor any bracha at all! It is forbidden to eat.

[Because it is poison](http://kosherfood.about.com/b/2013/09/25/psa-dont-eat-that-etrog.htm). In order to make it look so lovely, they dip it in a bunch of toxic chemicals.

> Unfortunately, while researching recipes, I learned that the etrog crops designated for use on Sukkot tend to be so heavily treated with pesticide that they're essentially toxic to consume. That's a terrible shame, since the etrog is supposed to be  notable among the four species as being the only one that has both fragrance and taste. Even more concerning is that heavy pesticide use is a health hazard for the farmers who tend the etrogim. Unfortunately, we've placed such priority on the superficial beauty of the pri eitz hadar -- fruit of the beautiful tree -- that etrogim are now literally too pretty to eat.

[And](http://jcarrot.org/the-toxic-etrog-read-before-you-eat):

> I have now heard from two individuals, one of whom worked on an esrik farm, that we should under no circumstances eat our esrogim. Because there is so much pressure for the fruit to be as beautiful as possible, the esrogim are drenched with toxic pesticides, herbicides, and fungicides to an even greater extent than typical in conventional agriculture.

Comment: here by the way is an answer. http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?srch=1&orderby=&q=etrog&cat=1 But regardless of downvotes, I believe the answer I provided should be the true answer. Because otherwise someone will poison himself. Plus other discussions do not apparently take into consideration that modern esrogim are poisonous.

Comment: do you have a source that just as one doesnt make a blessing on non-kosher food, so too one does not bless on a poisonous food, (were he to eat it)?