# Two Riddles on Brachos

Tags: blessing, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I was eating at a family's house on Shabbos, and one the sons receives a dvar Torah to share with the family, along with two irrelevant riddles, typically halachic edge-cases. This week, the riddles were:

(1) How can you say 12/13 (I don't remember which) brachos on one fruit?

(2) What is an act that if you do it by accident, you say a bracha, but if you do it on purpose, you don't say a *bracha*?

For the first one, I immediately thought: "*esrog*". You say *shehechyanu* once and *al netilas lulav* six times, as well as lehafrish terumos and maaseros if applicable. Additionally, [at least according to some shitas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34724/is-the-shehechiyanu-bracha-recited-when-eating-an-esrog-fruit), you could make a *shehechyanu* on eating the *esrog*, and you would certainly make *al pri haeitz* plus *borei nefashos*. That gets you to 10. I thought of turning the *esrog* into jam and making two *brachas* over eating it, but that seemed like cheating.

For the second one, I was thinking during the *omer*, or eating non-kosher food... something along those lines. But none of those are exact, so I'm really not sure.

Any ideas would be appreciated! There was no answer key and I'm very curious.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140/759

Comment: The first one is easy. Take an orange out of the fridge and say הנותן ריח טוב בפירות and smell it and put it back in the fridge. Repeat every morning for 12/13 days.

Comment: Hi @A.Lavie just a heads up this may be closed as historically riddles are deemed against mi yodeya policy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for what the original author of a question was thinking, in a format in which the original author (not the post author in this case) deliberately hides details that they know in order to make the question challenging. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/riddle-questions-on-se/

Comment: @IsaacMoses mod note, we have a riddle close reason, it's just not used enough to leave active. You have to deactivate the modesty one, activate riddle, use it, and then deactivate it and reactivate the modesty one.

Comment: 2) Rav Ovadiah Yosef in Yechave Daat 2:16 rules that a Kohen who kills someone by accident (באנס) is still allowed to continue to ישא את כפיו (priestly blessing), but if it is בשוגג or worse, then not (SA OC 128:35)? So the answer would be "a Cohen killing someone". Is שוגג "accident" as it involves some level of negligence? Does the beracha have to be _on_ the act?

Comment: @A.Lavie if you accidentally do not daven for example you can make all those brachas again, if you intentionally do not daven you cannot make up.

Comment: @A.Lavie you can smell the Esrog getting you to 11... Al Ha'Etz might be counted as "two brachas" perhaps according to the questioner?

Answer (score 1):

For riddle 2: Found something related to Pesach which is coming up: Mabye when destroying the Chametz on Chol Hamoed, then a blessing is recited if all the following conditions were fulfilled:

One did not do Mechirat Chametz.

The Chametz was not found, or known of, during Bedikat Chametz

All the Chametz that was found or known of during the Bedikah has already been burned.

It is at least a Kezayit in size, even if he nullified his Chametz before Pesach, or is less than a Kezayit in size but one did not nullify his Chametz before Pesach, and it is not considered automatically nullified. However, if the Chametz is less than a Kezayit and was nullified before Pesach, then a blessing is not recited upon destroying it.

Furthermore, if this less than Kezayit nullified piece is dirty, it does not even need to be destroyed.

The Chametz is Biblically considered Chametz.

This is held by: Shulchan Aruch Harav, Be'er heitev Orach Chaim 446:2, Magen Avraham 446:1 and others.

Source is: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/one-who-finds-chametz-in-his-property-on-pesach/#_ftnref19

Comment: Avishai, good work! Although I think the riddle is about something that one makes a blessing 'only' when done by accident, however in your case it can be done even intentionally when one burns his chametz in the correct time

Comment: shayachagigah, I appreciate it, I think we need @A. Lavie to clarify if its a case if one makes a blessing "only" when done by accident or not, but I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the Mitzva of שכחה! The Torah commands in דברים כד,יט "When you reap the harvest in your field and overlook a sheaf in the field, do not turn back to get it; it shall go to the stranger, the fatherless, and the widow —in order that the LORD your God may bless you in all your undertakings" (from translation of Sefaria). Now if there is a blessing to make on this Mitzva then here's the answer to riddle 2!

Comment: Seems unlikely there's a blessing on that mitzva. There's no action and you can't say the blessing before doing the mitzva.

Comment: Maybe OP misremembered the riddle, and the actual question what what action can you do that is only a mitzva if you do it by accident.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe OP's riddle was referring to vidui ma'aseir as a bracha ("*Hashkifa mim'on kodsh'cha... uvareich es 'am'cha es Yisra'eil*"), even though shichcha isn't actually m'akeiv the vidui (*Ma'aseir Sheini* 5:10).